# How to effectively get gps average speed in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to find the average of gps speed using gps
I put the values obtained through LocationListener into an arrayList and found the average value.

However, as the value increases over time, the data becomes large and inefficient.

Is there a more efficient way to average the gps speed?

```
ArrayList<Float> arrGpsSpeed = new ArrayList<>();
arrGpsSpeed.add(location.getSpeed());

float sum = 0;
for(int i=0;i<arrGpsSpeed.size();i++)
{
    sum += arrGpsSpeed.get(i);
}

float avgGpsSpeed = sum / arrGpsSpeed.size();
```

Comment: Sorry, you cannot call that an average speed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int totalSpeed = 0;
in numSamples = 0;

//When you get a new speed
totalSpeed+= newSpeed;
numSamples++;

avgSpeed = totalSpeed/numSamples;
```

No need to keep all the individual speeds, just keep the running total and the number of samples in it.

Comment: Average speed is total distance devided by total time. Your formula does not make sense.

Comment: @blackapps Yes, it does.  Average speed is distance over time.  Its also the average value of a bunch of speed values if taken at regular intervals.  The average of an set of values is the sum of the values/number of values.  This gets average speed and is absolutely correct.

Comment: Lets put it another way-  let's say at time t=0, you're at 0.  at 1, you're at 5.  At 2 you're at 20.  at 3 you're at 50.  At 4 you're at 80.  Distance/time= 20.  Now your speeds for those intervals are 5, 15, 30, 30 .  Adding them up, you get 80.  Divide by the number of samples, you get 20.   This algorithm also works with irregular intervals if you weigh the samples by the time difference between samples.

Comment: `if taken at regular intervals.` Indeed. But you dont have them with a location listener. OP was already wrong. You could have corrected OP to begin with. With an equal amount of code you could have summed total distance and total time.

Comment: @blackapps ANd the algorithm is trivially adjusted for that.  And depending on the degree of accuracy needed, the pings of a gps are frequent enough that it can be ignored.  I'd be far more concerned about the accuracy of the gps and the normal amount of wobble in its resutls than I would be about the interval differences.

Comment: @blackapps Not to mention-  you can specify the frequency of location updates from GPS on ANdroid.  If you're tracking say the speed of a human and getting the location every 30s-  the difference between getting it every 30.5s and 30s will be so trivial that it doesn't matter (less than 2% inaccuracy).  Unless you're looking for physics experiment level accuracy, in which case GPS is far and away not accurate enough.  The GPS will by far be the least accurate part of the setup

Comment: Well i hope OP realises what it is an average speed.